# How to render CSS3DObjects over WebGlRenderer Objects?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, three.js

I´m trying to render an `<iframe>` with the `CSS3DRenderer` to a `_3dScene` in `three.js`, but the `iframe` is always overlaying the object in the WebGl `scene`.

How to fix this overlap issue? The `iframe` is right in the middle of the object, and still visible at any time.

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is how i init the `CSS3DRenderer`:

```
private _init3DRenderer()
    {
        this._3DRenderer = new CSS3DRenderer();
        this._3DRenderer.setSize(this.css3dContainer.nativeElement.clientWidth, this.css3dContainer.nativeElement.clientHeight);
        this._3DRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        this._3DRenderer.domElement.style.zIndex = '0';
        this._3DRenderer.domElement.style.top = "0";
        this.css3dContainer.nativeElement.appendChild(this._3DRenderer.domElement);
    }
```

as well as initializing the `WebGlRenderer`:

```
private _initRenderer()
    {
        this._renderer = new WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
        this._renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        this._renderer.setSize(this.webglContainer.nativeElement.clientWidth, this.webglContainer.nativeElement.clientHeight);
        this._renderer.outputEncoding = sRGBEncoding;
        this._renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
        this._renderer.shadowMap.type = PCFSoftShadowMap;
        this.webglContainer.nativeElement.appendChild(this._renderer.domElement);
    }
```

after initialization im adding an object to the WebG as well as the iframe.

```
let div = document.createElement("div");
        let iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        iframe.style.width = "100%";
        iframe.style.height = "100%";
        iframe.src = url;

        div.style.width = "100%";
        div.style.height = "100%";
        div.style.zIndex = "2";
        div.style.scale = ".5";
        div.appendChild(iframe);

        let cssObject = new CSS3DObject(div);
        this._3Dscene.add(cssObject);
```

the 2 different scenes, are sharing the same camera object and get rendered like so:

```
private _render()
    {
        this._renderer?.render(this._scene, this._camera);
        this._3DRenderer?.render(this._3Dscene, this._camera);
    }
```

html template

```html
<div (window:resize)="onWindowResize($event)"
     #webglContainer
     style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute;">
</div>
<div #css3dContainer
     style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;">
</div>
```